# How can i find the Hostname of Remote database in Toad

Tags: connection-string, connection-pooling, toad, hostname

i am trying to connect to the remote database.With given username and password ,i am able to connect in toad.but in the code while handling connection pooling i am getting null connection.so i want to recheck the hostname for this particular DB?how can i check it in Toad?

```
String  url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:dbname";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");   
                System.out.println("got the connection"+connection);
```

i tried connecting using the credentials which i am havving but i getting null connection.i want to recheck the hostname..any idea how can i check the hostname in toad for remote Database?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
SELECT  host_name FROM v$instance
```